# How to remove (Windows 8.1) label from projects in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

Ok, this is a little OCD. I apologize.

In Visual Studio 2013, there's an additional label in the Solution Explorer that identifies projects' Windows version. For example, I have a Win8 project called:

`MyCompany.SomeNameSpace.Client.Win8`

However, in the solution explorer, it shows up like this:

`MyCompany.SomeNameSpace.Client.Win8 (Windows 8.1)`

When you have several Win8 projects, they ALL have that label. It looks something like this:

```
MyCompany.SomeNameSpace.Core (Windows 8.1)
MyCompany.SomeNameSpace.UI (Windows 8.1)
MyCompany.SomeNameSpace.Presentation (Windows 8.1)
MyCompany.SomeNameSpace.Client.Win8 (Windows 8.1)
```

It's unnecessary. Anyone know how to remove that?

Answer (score 0):

No one can remove it, because of the following reasons:

1. Visual Studio 2013 creates windows 8.1 projects only.
2. As shown below all the projects are targeted as windows 8.1 in every project properties.

   [image]
3. It also differentiate between windows 8 and windows 8.1 project, as you can also allow to open windows 8 project in visual studio 2013.

Hope this points help you.
Thank You